# wordpress widget plugin color picker do not work correctly

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Need to add color picker to the widget plugin.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );        
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker-script-handle', plugins_url('js/wp-color-picker-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
```

In wp-color-picker-script.js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".color-picker").wpColorPicker();   
});
```

If I write the above code, after clicking the save button, color picker dissapear and shows just a text box.

If I write:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".color-picker").wpColorPicker();  
  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    $(".color-picker").wpColorPicker();
  });
});
```

It duplicates color picker.

If I remove the first $(".color-picker").wpColorPicker();  The color picker appears when the save button is clicked.

What is the correct way to add color picker to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit your code like this it works fine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('#widgets-right .color-picker, .inactive-sidebar .color-picker').wpColorPicker();
            });
            jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                jQuery('#widgets-right .color-picker, .inactive-sidebar .color-picker').wpColorPicker();
            });
```

Comment: Works fine for me.